# Force error state in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In a factory in my app there is such a piece of code:

```
    upload_and_save: function(model){
                var personalInfoUpdated = $q.defer();
                if (typeof(model.image) === 'object') {
                    var file = model.image[0];
                    if (file.size > MyPersonal.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                        return { $promise: personalInfoUpdated.reject() }; // THAT DOESN'T WORK
                    } else {
                        $upload.upload({
                        url: '/api/profiles/myprofile/edit/',
                        method: 'PUT',
                        file: file,
                        fields: model
                        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            personalInfoUpdated.resolve(data);
                        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config){
                            console.debug('ERROR with file!', data);
                            personalInfoUpdated.reject(data);
                        });
return { $promise: personalInfoUpdated.promise };
                    }
```

As you can see - filesize validation goes first. What i'd like to do is to reject file at once if it's too large, but i guess i need to make some fake call to resource that would force erroneous state. Or maybe there are some other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `personalInfoUpdated.reject()` then return `personalInfoUpdated.promise`. The reject function does not return the promise.